# Do i need synchronization in below example?

Tags: c++, oop, mutex

As per cppreference document:

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment)
> can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr
> without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies
> and share ownership of the same object.

As i understood from cppreference, you don't need to put synchronization as you are calling different member functions using different instances of shared_ptr which points to the same object.
Please correct me if i understood wrong.and also give small example to understand it clearly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Demo
{
public:
    int Value;
    Demo():Value(10){}

    void fun1()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<300000; i++)
        {
            Value = Value + i;
            std::cout << "Value1 :" << Value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void fun2()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<300000; i++)
        {
            Value = Value + i;
            std::cout << "Value2 :" << Value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void fun3()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<300000; i++)
        {
            Value = Value + i;
            std::cout << "Value3 :" << Value << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr1(new Demo);
    std::thread t1(&Demo::fun1, ptr1);

    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr2(ptr1);
    std::thread t2(&Demo::fun2, ptr2);

    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr3(ptr2);
    std::thread t3(&Demo::fun3, ptr3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

//output:

> Getting random(asynchronized) output as shown below:

```
 Value3 :70993659Value2 :
71000412
Value1 :71006910Value2 :
70993659Value1 :71013664
```

Comment: yes you do : std::mutex/std::scoped_lock. And when working with threads, also learn about lambda functions `std::thread t1([=]{ ptr->fun1();} );` (it is easier to pass more complex functions to threads including explicit capture semantics)

Comment: What does the very next sentence say? about the data race and stuff?

Comment: @Atmo: looks like that sentence is saying if i am using same instance of shared_ptr but here i am using multiple instances of shared_ptr ie. ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 like that. correct me if i understood wrong.

Comment: The sentence is saying that the methods **of std:;shared_ptr<T>** are thread-safe, not the methods from your class.

Answer (score 1):

***All member functions** (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances **of shared_ptr** without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object.*

`shared_ptr`'s member functions can be called without synchronization. However, you still need to synchronize member function calls of the template type, i.e. `Demo`.

`fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3` are member of `Demo`, not member of `shared_ptr`. So you still need to use lock to protect them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need synchronization for both `value_` and `std::cout`.

Beside that, the sum of the first 300,000 positive integers is: 45,000,000,000 (45 billion). X 3 threads is: 13.5 billion. To avoid undefined behavior when a signed integer exceeds `INT_MAX` (2,147,483,647), it is advisable to change its data type to unsigned integer and to use wider integer data types such as `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>


class Demo
{
public:
    uint64_t value_;

    Demo() : value_(10) {}

    void fun1()
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);

            value_ += i;
            std::cout << "Value1 :" << value_ << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void fun2()
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);

            value_ += i;
            std::cout << "Value2 :" << value_ << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void fun3()
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);

            value_ += i;
            std::cout << "Value3 :" << value_ << std::endl;
        }
    }

protected:
    std::mutex mutex_{};
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr1(new Demo);
    std::thread t1(&Demo::fun1, ptr1);

    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr2(ptr1);
    std::thread t2(&Demo::fun2, ptr2);

    std::shared_ptr<Demo> ptr3(ptr2);
    std::thread t3(&Demo::fun3, ptr3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```